# automatic generation of EAN13 code

Tags: odoo

how to automatically create the EAN13 code when adding a new product without the use of button. is there a solution or Odoo must install a module or what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit the create method of the model, this way when a product is being created you can have it create an EAN13 code.

Comment: there is no module for automatic creation of ean13 code without button click ?

Comment: I'm not sure on that, a quick search on Odoo apps didn't yield any results. It doesn't take much time to do it yourself